# Run parachain as local regular chain

Tags: parachain, runtime, collator, local

Working on a parachain, the executable that is build is a collator node. It will run both the parachain and the relay-chain nodes.

For pallet development (pure product, unrelated to the chain being a standalone or a parachain, just the stuff that make this chain special), it's not ideal to have to run a local relay chain + the collator node just to test you runtime and call a few extrinsics.

What I am looking for is for an easy way to run the parachain runtime as a standalone. Basically, run the chain runtime without the added Cumulus part. Like I would have running `cargo run --dev` on a regular, non parachain, chain.

Comment: What prevents you from migrating the code to a [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) for pallet development purposes?

Comment: That's probably fairly unwieldy to do.

Answer (score 2):

you may use some `manual-seal` consensus or just `aura` with some `MockValidationDataProvider` to mock data from relaychain.

take Acala's dev runtime [Mandala](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/2fa44c17c61a9e88bfa9509d6c855422c9544b5c/node/cli/src/command.rs#L473) as reference

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `node-template` to develop any business logic and later on migrate your pallets to the `parachain-template`. As long as you work with the same version on both `templates`, moving pallets from one to another should be no problem.

The same applies for node and runtime files, you can simply add your modifications to the `parachain-template` to make it work.